# What should be provided as action-name in az-cli command while creating sentinel alert?

Tags: azure-cli, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to create a sentinel alert by using the below az-cli command :

```
az sentinel alert-rule action create --action-name
                                     --resource-group
                                     --rule-name
                                     --workspace-name
                                     [--etag]
                                     [--logic-app-resource-id]
                                     [--trigger-uri]
```

Have followed this article but it doesn't have any examples for the command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sentinel/alert-rule/action?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sentinel-alert-rule-action-create

What should be provided as parameter to action-name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ````
> az sentinel alert-rule action create --action-name
>                                      --resource-group
>                                      --rule-name
>                                      --workspace-name
>                                      [--etag]
>                                      [--logic-app-resource-id]
>                                      [--trigger-uri] ```
> ````

Here `--eta`, `--logic-app-resource-id`, `--trigger-uri` paramters are optional where **`--action-name`** is the action group name.

For action name, go to the Azure Portal > Monitor > Alerts > Action Groups > create an action group for which resource that alert rules should be created:

[image]

Comment: Have created one query related to az-cli alert rule creation. Facing issue while creating. Can you please look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74559678/how-to-create-sentinel-alerts-via-az-cli-command