# How to create sentinel alerts via az-cli command?

Tags: azure-cli, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to create sentinel alert using az-cli.

```
az sentinel alert-rule create —-name "test" --resource-group example-resources  --workspace-name example-workspace
```

But I'm facing this error even though name parameter is included in above command..

**Error:**

```
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
Model 'AAZObjectType' has no field named 'kind'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.42.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 233, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.42.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 663, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.42.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 726, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.42.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 697, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.42.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/aaz/_command.py", line 145, in __call__
    return self._handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/xxx/.azure/cliextensions/sentinel/azext_sentinel/aaz/latest/sentinel/alert_rule/_create.py", line 31, in _handler
    self._execute_operations()
  File "/Users/xxx/.azure/cliextensions/sentinel/azext_sentinel/aaz/latest/sentinel/alert_rule/_create.py", line 590, in _execute_operations
    self.AlertRulesCreateOrUpdate(ctx=self.ctx)()
  File "/Users/xxx/.azure/cliextensions/sentinel/azext_sentinel/aaz/latest/sentinel/alert_rule/_create.py", line 600, in __call__
    request = self.make_request()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.42.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/aaz/_operation.py", line 310, in make_request
    self.content, self.form_content, self.stream_content)
  File "/Users/xxx/.azure/cliextensions/sentinel/azext_sentinel/aaz/latest/sentinel/alert_rule/_create.py", line 680, in content
    _builder.discriminate_by("kind", "Fusion")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.42.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/aaz/_content_builder.py", line 159, in discriminate_by
    schema.discriminate_by(prop_name, prop_value)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/azure-cli/2.42.0/libexec/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/cli/core/aaz/_field_type.py", line 222, in discriminate_by
    raise AAZUnknownFieldError(self, key)
azure.cli.core.aaz.exceptions.AAZUnknownFieldError: Model 'AAZObjectType' has no field named 'kind'
```

Can anyone please suggest me out regarding the same ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with —-name where it should be as --name. Update it and see if it resolves the error. Or else give -n instead as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sentinel/alert-rule?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sentinel-alert-rule-create).